# Scope issue with a class being instantiated in a button

Tags: c++, qt, scope

I have some code that is residing within a button in a Qt GUI. This code instantiates a class that I developed, which does some processing, and returns an unsigned char**, like so:

```
void Viewer::button_click()
{
    Classifier *pc = new Classifier(hhfile, vvfile, hvfile,aoix, aoiy,aoiw, aoih, target, filter );
    unsigned char **data = pc->classify();
.
.
.
}
```

The first time I click the button, the array data has the correct information in it. Without changing any of the parameters to the Classifier class, if I click the button again, data comes back FUBAR'd.

I am not doing any explicit deleting of data or pc, but should I have to? These are residing within the button function scope, so I guess I thought I should get the exact same results no matter what is actually happening with data, or happening within the Classify class. Is this correct? What are the possible reasons that passing the same parameters to a class twice in a row would give different results?

Comment: This code creates a new instance of the Classifier class each time you click the button. Do you ever delete that object? Why do you allocate it on the heap? Is that necessary?

Comment: what are you referring to "it", the Classifier object? I never delete the object, thinking it is going out of scope and automatically deallocated as the button_click function is over, is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Derek it's going out of scope and therefore leaving a memory leak in your case... you need to either use an automatic variable or delete your pointer before leaving scope.

Comment: @Derek: Without showing us more of the functionality behind Classifier, or pretty much anything else, we can't tell you much.

Comment: I have tried to make it an automatic variable as well, and I am still getting funny results. What I dont understand is why does it matter what the classify() function or this particular instance of the Classifier() class does. I am creating a whole new one, so the 2nd time should be identical to the first. None of the parameters get changed within the class, at any time, and I pass in new copies of the parameters the next time. Further, if, within this button_click function I create anotehr identical class intance, and a new unsigned char **data2..I get the same results in data and data2

Comment: Derek: this classify function must be DOING something with the variables you pass in your class ctor, so what it is DOING could have an error in it. Plenty of ways to go wrong in C++, just take my word for it!

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean when you say " data comes back FUBAR'd"

Comment: There are a lot of zero'd out entries in the array, and incorrect values in other places, but enough of them are correct that I can tell that it is at least "in the ballpark"

Comment: @derek, the rule of thumb is, every new needs a delete, every new[] needs a delete[]. unless you do that you get memory leaks. of course you can use shared pointers to have that done automatically for you. but in your care there is no need to allocate that object on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

`new` is the keyword the language uses when you specify you want something that survives *beyond* function scope. For function-scope objects, you just declare them, that is,

```
Classifier pc(hhfile, vvfile, hvfile,aoix, aoiy,aoiw, aoih, target, filter );
```

Whether or not you need to do anything with the memory returned by `classify()`, I couldn't say without seeing the source.

The most likely problem is that your arguments are references or pointers and you're modifying that data when you're not supposed to.

Comment: The arguments are all just strings, and I am passing in the same strings every time. I guess I will try explicity freeing the data array and see if that helps, but im just not sure why I should have to (when not concerned about memory leaks, i mean)

Comment: One should always be concerned about memory leaks :)

Answer (score 0):

if `classify();` is working on the same data for each call to click you will be altering it anew each time and so perhaps get data corruption.  I have no idea what classify() does, so hard to say.

Also, is there a reason for Classifier being a pointer and not just an automatic variable?

Then you are creating it in local scope on each click, so the data contained in that object is gone each time you leave scope, and here you are even leaking it with the pointer, as you are not doing proper memory management.

EDIT:

I'd do this:

```
Classifier pc(hhfile, vvfile, hvfile,aoix, aoiy,aoiw, aoih, target, filter );
unsigned char **data = pc.classify();
```

Now unless your Classifier class is doing something odd in the classify function, you should get the results you expect, per the data you've given us.

Comment: classify should be working on new data each time - all of the parameters passed to the constructor are passed by value - so there should be no changes. I can modify those parameters in my gui. However, if I am getting bogus results whether they are the same or different

Comment: What would classifier be doing that is "odd" exactly? All of the parameters i am passing in are strings, and since i am instantiating a new Classifier every time and passing in the same strings, shouldnt it be giving the same results?

Comment: it should, but hard to tell, since I haven't seen it.